# How to show and hide multiple element in one selector jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to show the hidden element with ID `hidden_element` when i click the element with class `show_hidden_element` , and close the element with ID `hidden_element` when i click element with ID `close_hidden_element` , if i just make one my script can work fine, but i have three element with same CLASS and ID, it cant work, somebody please help.

this is my script

```
 <article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div id="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div id="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div id="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>
```

my jQuery Script is

```
    $(this).find(".show_hidden_element").click( function(){
        $(this).find("#hidden_element").show();
    });
    $(this).find("#close_hidden_element").click( function(){
        $(this).find("#hidden_element").hide();
    });
```

Comment: First, element ID must be unique is scope of document (you case may work with jQuery which is quite fault tolerant but other libraries mail fail on such setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `id` and `class` is that id is unique, class is not.
Also an element may have multiple classes, but unique id.

use `class="close_hidden_element button_close"`.

```
<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a class="close_hidden_element button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a class="close_hidden_element button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a class="close_hidden_element button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>
```

And your jquery should be.

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.show_hidden_element',function(){
    $(".hidden_element").show();
});
$(document).on('click', 'div.close_hidden_element',function(){
    $(".hidden_element").hide();
});
```

**Advice**: read this  http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

Elements on a page must have **UNIQUE** IDs. If you want this to work, you'll need to change them to classes. Do you want each of the `<article>`s to hide/show only by their respective triggers?

```
 <article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a class="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a class="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a class="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("article").on("click",".show_hidden_element",function(){
    $(this).find(".hidden_element").show();
});
$("article").on("click",".close_hidden_element",function(){
    $(this).closest(".hidden_element").hide();
});
```

Actually, this doesn't work quite right because of the placement of the `show_hidden_element` class. You might be better off having the `<a close="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>` being a toggle, like this:

```
<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                 <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
 <a class="close_hidden_element" class="button_close">&times;</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

$(function () {
    $("article").on("click", ".close_hidden_element", function () {
        $(".hidden_element").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show me how do that? i want `<article>` can show the hidden element on the inside, and then the hidden element can be close by `<a id="close_hidden_element" >` on the inside of hidden element

Comment: My apologies for the multiple answers... it appears that some folks on here are simply active to jack up their scores, even when someone else has posted an answer 7 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same id for multiple elements. You have to convert the id into class for all the id="hidden_element"(and others too) and then use something like this.

```
<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="close_hidden_element1" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="close_hidden_element2" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>

<article class="post show_hidden_element">
    <div class="hidden_element">
        <div class="read_box">
            <div class="read_box_content">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                <a id="close_hidden_element3" class="button_close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</article>
```

jquery

```
$(".show_hidden_element").click( function(){
    $(this).find(".hidden_element").show();
});

$(".button_close").click( function(){
    $(this).closest(".hidden_element").hide();
});
```