# How to hide multiple value in once with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked for it but couldn't find the answer i have this :

```
$("#id option[value='1']").hide();
```

It'll hide my option number 1 in dropdown but i'm trying to hide more and i could just copy paste this with value 2 etc but i guess i can do this in once ! But how ?

I have tried something like this

```
$("#id option[value='1,2,3']").hide();
```

but it's not working, also tried

```
    var something = [1,2,3];
    $("#id option[value='something']").hide();
```

i'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: `var something = [1, 2, 3];
$("#SoinsCourantsViewModel_UniteConsultationCAS option").filter(something.map(function(value) {
  return '[value="' + value + '"]'
}).join()).hide();
`

Comment: not working as well :/ thanks @ArunPJohny , that works :)

Comment: How about `$("#id option[value='1'], #id option[value='2'], #id option[value='3']").hide();`

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: that could work but my id lenght would make this awful ! But yes it's a good one

Comment: Such questions have been already answered many times, please try to make an effort, better check this - 
Duplicates-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967081/show-hide-multiple-divs-with-jquery and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500443/how-to-show-and-hide-multiple-element-in-one-selector-jquery

Comment: I've already seen those subjects. I'm asking because i couldn't resolve my issue. And also i don't think it's a duplicate it's not the same subject.

Comment: Duplicate doesn't mean it should be with same title bro, anyway, I think you check the first link in the above comment, hopefully you can get some better solution for this !

Answer (score 2):

try this following code:

If you want to hide:

```
var something = [1,2,3];
$('#id option').filter(function () {
    return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value), something ) > -1);
}).hide();
```

and again required show it:

```
var something = [1,2,3];
    $('#id option').filter(function () {
        return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value), something ) > -1);
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be setting a data attribute to the option, categorizing them

and then hide/show with `$('option[data-category="'+X+'"], $('#id')).hide()`

The array map solution (stated in comments) would work too

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript array:

```
var something = [1,2,3];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
    $("#id option[value='"+something[i]+"']").hide();
}
```